# Pagespeed with Wordpress in subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, pagespeed

I have a Bitnami Wordpress install that uses Pagespeed. I had to move Wordpress to it's own directory and add SSL cert so the blog now resides at https://www.example.com/blog. All seems to work okay except for a 404 in the console where Pagespeed is trying to post to https://www.example.com/mod_pagespeed_beacon?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fblog%2F which throws a 404 error.

I've never used Pagespeed before but I imagine the problem here is that it's trying to post to the root of my site rather than /blog. Is there a way to fix this so that it posts to the `/blog` subdirectory instead? I tried adding `ModPagespeedMapOriginDomain www.example.com/blog www.example.com` but that didn't work.